# Why there is no kdevelop on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, centos6

I tried to use kdevelop on CentOS 6, but unlike CentOS 5.*,  I couldn't find such an option under Programming. I searched through the package list, no mention of KDevelop either, does anybody have any idea what happened to kdevelop on CentOS 6? Is it simply dropped from package list, or I need to do something fancy to continue use it?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the latest KDevelop release (=v4.2.3) requires kdelibs-devel v4.5.0, while CentOS 6 contains v4.3.4.

The most recent version of KDevelop possible on CentOS is v4.0.2.
I've build it from source, but this version KDevelop seems to be far from complete (e.g. I did not find how to create a project).

I have no idea if CentOS 6.1 (or later) will contain a newer version of KDE?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend getting the epel repository, then trying to use `yum` to get what you need.

How to install the epel repository: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-5x-or-6x

then something like the following may give you what you need:

```
yum search kdelibs
yum install kdelibs*
```

Comment: This worked for me on centos7.2.   epel provides kdevelop

Answer (score 0):

You can use KDevelop 3.3.4 from the CentOS 5 repo.

I have installed [KDevelop 3.3.4 from here](http://pkgs.org/centos-5-rhel-5/centos-rhel-x86_64/kdevelop-3.3.4-1.fc6.x86_64.rpm/download/) and it works fine on my CentOS 6.2 x64!