# Is kdevelop available in centos 7

Tags: centos, kdevelop

I heard that Centos 7 has been released recently. I was not able to install kdevelop in centos 6. Has anyone here installed centos 7 and tried with the installation of kdevelop or does it comes up with unsupported kdelibs version still.

Comment: Has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340375/why-there-is-no-kdevelop-on-centos-6